# React sub-object click effects parent's click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, carbon-design-system

I am trying to create a react app using carbon design.

```
        <HeaderName
          element={Link}
          to="/campaigns"
          prefix=" "
          className={["navbar-header", `${path == "/campaigns" ? "selected" : ""}`]}
        >
          Campaigns
          {campaingCount !== 0 ? (
            <Tag
              filter
              onClose={(e) => {
                e.stopPropagation();
                dispatch(deleteAllCampaign());
              }}
              title="Clear Filter"
              type={undefined}
            >
              {campaingCount}
            </Tag>
          ) : null}
        </HeaderName>
```

Here 'to' attribute of HeaderName routes the page to a url, as a sub object, Tag has its own close button and 'onClose' event is triggered when close button is clicked.

PROBLEM: When I click on the close button of the Tag, Page is routed to '/campaigns' again and all the state is deleted and it effects the business logic.

Comment: Depends how you implement the `Tag` component. Have you tried to place the `stopPropagation` inside the click event from Tag? Just to check if the propagation is correctly stopped?

Comment: Tag is carbon desing component and just a div, and there is a closing button inside which triggers 'onClose' event of the Tag. Inside this event, I used **stopPropagation** . Even so, HeaderName's click event is fired. @Guilhermevrs

Comment: I see...By checking the code (https://github.com/carbon-design-system/carbon/blob/master/packages/react/src/components/Tag/Tag.js#L48) they seem to be already doing the stopPropagation, so problem must come from somewhere else.
Is it possible to set a github repo for me check?